# batch file commands in powershell execute in a different command prompt

Tags: windows, batch-file, powershell

I'm using this new machine, so as usual I go and set the execution policy so that I can use my profile script, after doing that however powershell now opens all batch files in a new cmd.exe window.

I tried undoing this step but it's still the same so I think it has nothing to do with the script execution policy, also I still have the powershell window in which I originally set the execution policy and this one behaves normally, only new windows have this problem.

I may have installed some software, but nothing is related to windows, and I tried setting the PATH variable to its exact value in the working window but it does not work.

Comment: Show the code that you are using to execute a batch file.

Comment: Does `$env:PATHEXT` include '`.BAT`'?

Comment: @Rynant yes this was it, what happened is that I installed Tcl, and it added a `PATHEXT` variable to the user variables with the value `.tcl`, this new variable removed the effect of the system variable `PATHEXT` which now only contains, I removed `PATHEXT` from user variables and added `.tcl` to `PATHEXT` in the system variables and now it works, so please add the answer to get the credit

Comment: @MysticOdin Glad that worked; I've added my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Batch files will open in a new window if the `PATHEXT` environment variable does not contain '`.BAT`' as one of the executable extensions.

To check the variable, enter the following at the PowerShell prompt: `$env:PATHEXT`